# JavaScript/PHP cookie serialization methods?

Tags: php, javascript, serialization, cookies

I have a form which I would like to store the values of in a cookie so the user doesn't have to re-enter the form every visit. (The form is a few selects to filter search results.)

I would like for the cookie serialization to easily be readable from JavaScript (obviously to set the form `onLoad`), but I'd also like to be able to read the cookie easily from PHP (so that I can use the form data to filter search results).

How would I go about serializing a form with selects that have `multiple="multiple"` set into a cookie and have it be easily readable in JavaScript and PHP?

Please don't preach about validation, I'm doing that correctly on the server-side.

If there's a smarter solution to my problem please let me know.

BTW: I'm using CodeIgniter on the server and Prototype/Scriptaculous JavaScript libraries.

**Solution:** Used Prototype's [`Object.toJSON(`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/object/tojson)[`Form.serialize(form, true))`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/serialize) for JavaScript, and used PHP's [`json_decode(string, bool)`](http://ca.php.net/json_decode) to get an associative array in PHP from the JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [JSON format](http://json.org/) that is already implemented in several languages.

Comment: +1. This method should be quite quick as PHP already has json encoding / decoding functions.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend YAML.  It's basically designed as a common serialization method for several languages, including JavaScript and PHP.

From the YAML site:

> YAML was designed to meet the
>   serialization needs of Perl, Python,
>   Ruby, Tcl, PHP, Javascript and Java.
>   It was also designed to be
>   interoperable between those languages.
>   That means YAML serializations
>   produced by Perl can be processed by
>   Python.

Here's a sitepoint article on the topic:

http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2004/04/22/serializing-php-data-structures-for-javascript/

The YAML site:

http://www.yaml.org/