# packing tree-like structures into a cookie

Tags: javascript, serialization

I would like to be able to store a tree-like structure in a cookie. Ideally, I would like to have something that easily serealizes/deserializes a javascript plain object.

JSON might be a good option, but a quick googling did not filtered out a mainstream approach how to serialize to JSON from JavaScript.

What is the best way to approach the problem?

**UPD**

Related questions bubbled up [Javascript / PHP cookie serialization methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651466/javascript-php-cookie-serialization-methods), which suggests using Prototype's `Object.toJSON`. I would prefer to stay with jQuery.

**UPD2**

It turned out that `window.JSON.stringify` might actually suffice in my case, but mentioned Douglas Crockford's library seems like a good fallback to support browsers where `JSON` property of the global object is not present.

Comment: How does your tree data look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is your friend.

A free and recognized implementation made by Douglas Crockford is available [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

I have used this method to read and store to HTML5's local storage without any problems.

Comment: Nice! It seems like a way to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

JSON is undoubtedly a good option. To have it work cross-browser include this file in your page https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js. Then use JSON.stringify() to convert to a string and store, and JSON.parse() to retrieve the object from the cookie.

Be aware that there can be [quite low character limits on a single cookie's length](http://myownplayground.atspace.com/cookietest.html), which any jsonified tree could hit, so you might want to preprocess your data before converting to JSON (e.g. replacing booleans with 1's and 0's, switching property names for abbreviated versions) and post-process to reverse these changes after retrieveing from your cookie.

If the amount of data you're storing is really large it may be better to store a session/identifier cookie which is used to retrieve the data from the server via an ajax request (or if you need a quick response on page load, output the data into a script tag) and save the data directly to the server via ajax requests instead of using a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

One more JSON serialization implementation as a jQuery plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/